# What does "locked at" <tag> mean when running "composer update <package>"?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to perform a `composer update <package>` but getting the following error:

> The requested package <package> (locked at <tag>, required as
> <version>) is satisfiable by <package>[<tag>] but these conflict
> with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Meanwhile, the tag `<tag>` exists as a string only in my composer.lock file, which I thought was only modified by `composer update`, not read back.

I tried running `composer why-not <package>`, but its output didn't really explain the issue:

> <program> <other-version> requires <package> (<version>)

What does 'locked at' mean in this context and how do I solve the issue?

Comment: What's your `minimum-stability` setting in your application's `composer.json` and what's the stability inside the `composer.json` on the `dev-*` branch of the package?

Comment: The dev-* branch of the package does not define a stability in its composer.json

Comment: It'd probably be easier for us to debug your issue if we had the concrete package-name and version of the package you're trying to use. Without it this is pretty theoretical as we're unable to re-create your concrete issue. If the package is on packagist -> please add it to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify a package name to `composer update` (e.g. `composer update somevendor/somepackage`), you're telling Composer that you want to update that package *and leave everything else at the current version* - you want to "lock" all the other packages where they are, and just update one.

That will only work if the new version of the package you specify is compatible with those already installed packages. If the new version requires a newer version of something else, or lists that it "conflicts with" a particular version, Composer will simply tell you that it can't do it.

The versions that the other packages are "locked at" are stored in the `composer.lock` file, but you should never edit that file by hand.

You have a few ways to tell Composer which packages it's allowed to update:

- Update more than one specific package at a time to resolve the specific problem: `composer update somevendor/somepackage somethingelse/somedependency`
- Update the selected package and all its dependencies *except the ones you've listed directly in your composer.json*: `composer update somevendor/somepackage --with-dependencies`
- Update the selected package *and all its dependencies*: `composer update somevendor/somepackage --with-all-dependencies`
- Just update everything: `composer update` with no arguments at all

All of these commands will still respect the version constraints you've specified manually in `composer.json`, you are just giving Composer *additional* instructions on the command-line about which packages it's allowed to update to meet those constraints.

Personally, I would advocate just running `composer update` with no arguments: if you want tighter control over when something gets updated, you can always list a more specific constraint in `composer.json`.

Comment: My question is: can one accomplish the same job with the require command ? what does the --update-with-dependencies option of the require command do ?

Answer (score 9):

The package is **locked** means the commit-hash of the last commit on the branch used with version-constraint `dev-<branch>` was saved during the last run of `composer update` in the lock-file to ensure deterministic (reproducible) builds upon deployment.

This commit-hash or tag is written to your lock-file (`composer.lock`) if you:

1. run `composer update [<package>]`

... or ...

2. run `composer install` with a `composer.json` present but not a lock-file in composer's current directory which does auto-generate the lock-file

Comment: yes, but doesn't a composer update simply overwrite any existing hashs in the composer.lock in case it changed? Being' locked' in this sense should not prevent the respective record to be overwritten, to my understanding.

Comment: While this answers the exact question of "what does this terminology mean", it doesn't really help users who are seeing this error.